# Is there a built-in way for converting a list to a function?

Tags: python, list, function

Suppose I have a Python list `lst`. I want to convert this to a function or callable, which may be done by:

```
def lst_as_function(idx):
    return lst[idx]
```

or (less preferably):

```
lst_as_lambda_function = lambda idx: lst[idx]
```

However, as this seems to be a very natural operation, I wondered whether there exists a built-in (perhaps more efficient) way to achieve this.

(To be a little bit more precise: Is there a Python built-in function `convert` such that I could write `lst_as_function = convert(lst)`?)

Does anybody know?

Comment: `lambda idx: lst[idx]` is as compact and bulit-in as it gets. Although I can't see a purpose for this at all...

Comment: Why don't you just use `lst[index]`, rather than `some_other_thing(index)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want to use the function `convert` as a key parameter in another function (and want to avoid using `def` or `lambda` if I can write `another_function(..., key=convert(lst))`.

Comment: @SebastianThomas Making a function just so that it would be passed as a callback argument is the main reason why there is `lambda` in the first place. You can use it in-line `some_function(..., key=lambda idx: lst[idx])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There actually is (if I understand your question correctly):

```
>>> a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
>>> f = a.__getitem__
>>> f(2)
30
```

Comment: Of course, why didn't I think of that? Thank you very much!